# Return <dd> knowing the previous <dt> beautiful soup - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I started using BeautifulSoup4 two days ago.
I want to get the `<dd>` knowing the previous tag (`<dt>`).
I tried to get the number of episodes( `<dt>Episodi</dt>`) etc from https://www.animeclick.it/anime/2683/yojouhan-shinwa-taikei but since they aren't static (it can be that sometimes the tag that I want isn't everytime the third tag, for example) I wanted to know how to get it.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know how to do it. That was my question: what should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `zip()` method to zip `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags together in this case. If `<dt>` tag will contain the text `Episodi` you know the next `<dd>` tags contains the number of episodes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.animeclick.it/anime/2683/yojouhan-shinwa-taikei')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for dt, dd in zip(soup.select('#dettagli dl > dt'),
                  soup.select('#dettagli dl > dd')):
    if 'Episodi' in dt.text.strip():
        print('Number of episodes:', dd.text.strip())
        break
```

Prints:

```
Number of episodes: 11
```